# Exception projecting LINQ to EF to View Model. Getting "only parameterless constructor and initializers" exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I know variations of this issue have been covered ad nauseum here on SO, but it seems like my code already matches what has been repeatedly marked as the answer.  I'm working on some reporting and have leveraged this pattern for a number of other similar reports without issue. I have a controller action like this:

```
public ActionResult Filter(ChecksClearingFilterVM Filter)
        {
            var Result = DataQuery(Filter).Select(a => new ChecksClearingResultVM
            {
                CheckAmount = a.Amount,
                CheckNumber = a.CheckNumber,
                Payee = a.NpoName,
                CheckClearDate = a.CheckClearDate,
                CheckDate = a.CheckDate,
            }).ToList(); 
            Filter.Result = Result;
            return View("ChecksClearingResult", Filter);
        }
```

And this is the view model in question:

```
public class ChecksClearingResultVM
    {
        public int? CheckNumber { get; set; }
        public string Payee { get; set; }
        public DateTime CheckDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CheckClearDate { get; set; }       
        public decimal CheckAmount { get; set; }       
    }
```

And the other view model:

```
public class ChecksClearingFilterVM
    {
        public int BankAccountId { get; set; }
        public SelectList SelectBankAccount { get; set; }
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ChecksClearingResultVM> Result { get; set; }
    }
```

It doesn't seem like i'm calling any constructor, much less one with parameters. It bombs on the projection. I'm especially confused because I have a handful of reports working just fine with this same design.

Maybe my problem is an issue with the DataQuery function? This is how it looks:

```
 public IQueryable<DistroPayment> DataQuery(ChecksClearingFilterVM Filter)
        {
            var wootz = Tds.DistroPayments
                .Where(b =>
                   b.BankAccountId == Filter.BankAccountId
                   && b.CheckClearDate.HasValue
                   || !b.CheckNumber.HasValue);

            if (Filter.StartDate.HasValue || Filter.StartDate.HasValue)
            {
                if (Filter.StartDate.HasValue)
                {
                    wootz = wootz.Where(x => x.CheckClearDate >= Filter.StartDate);
                }

                if (Filter.EndDate.HasValue)
                {
                    wootz = wootz.Where(x => x.CheckClearDate <= Filter.EndDate);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                wootz = wootz.Where(x => x.CheckClearDate >= new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1));
            }

            return wootz;
        }
```

As requested, here is my stack trace. Prepare for Wall-O-Text:

```
<!--

Message: Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.
Source: System.Data.Entity
StackTrace:
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.NewTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, NewExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.UnaryTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, UnaryExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.BinaryTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, BinaryExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input, DbExpressionBinding& binding)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SelectTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at TDS.UI.Controllers.ChecksClearingController.Filter(ChecksClearingFilterVM Filter) in C:\Users\gbisaccia.CREATEHOPE\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TruistConnect\DEVELOPMENT\TruistConnect\TDS.UI\Controllers\ChecksClearingController.cs:line 59
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)

-->
```

Comment: Please post your full exception stacktrace. It's hard to understand what error are you getting from your question and on which line this happens. Also could you show your `ChecksClearingFilterVM` class?

Comment: I also posted the other view model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wootz = wootz.Where(x => x.CheckClearDate >= new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1));
```

That doesn't look right. Entity Framework doesn't understand this constructor. You should be able to fix this part by making it a parameter:

```
var startOfYear = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1);
wootz = wootz.Where(x => x.CheckClearDate >= startOfYear);
```

A search also brings up [`EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.createdatetime.aspx) as an alternative.

(Note: I haven't checked if this is the only problem.)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much. I guess I wasn't scrutinizing the query construction method because stepping through it all worked. I didn't think about how none of that code would blow up until the query was actually executed. You nailed this one! Thanks again for the quick solution!